# Insert query não funciona no PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tenho a seguinte *query* que não esta funcionando no PHP, porque se rodo no SQL não apresenta nenhum problema.

```
sql= "INSERT INTO books (ISBN, Authorsname, Title, edition, year, publisher, 
category, quantityinstock, price) VALUES(".$ISBN.",'".$Authorsname."', 
'".$Title."', ".$edition.", ".$year.", '".$publisher."','".$category."', 
".$quantityinstock.",".$price.")"
```

Comment: da um `echo $sql;` e para ver o que o formulario está trazendo e testa a sql no banco, também vi que está faltando aspas simples em `$edition`

Comment: pensei que strings teriam de estar entre '' e "" e que inteiros apenas entre ""

Comment: Ou faça assim :  `$sql = "INSERT blabla (colunas) VALUES ('{$variavel1}', '{$variavel2}', '{$variavel3}' )"`

Comment: obrigado Max, ja deu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você faltou seguir mesma grafia, o primeiro **sem** aspas simples e o segundo **com** aspas simples

".$ISBN."   ....    ' ".$Authorsname." '

todos tem que estar entre aspas simples

```
VALUES('".$ISBN."','".$Authorsname."', '".$Title."', '".$edition."', '".$year."', '".$publisher."','".$category."', '".$quantityinstock."','".$price."')"
```

ou

```
VALUES('$ISBN','$Authorsname', '$Title', '$edition', '$year', '$publisher','$category', '$quantityinstock','$price')"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sql= "INSERT INTO `books` (`ISBN`, `Authorsname`, `Title`, `edition`, `year`, `publisher`, `category`, `quantityinstock`, `price`) VALUES('{$ISBN}','{$Authorsname}','{$Title}', '{$edition}', '{$year}', '{$publisher}','{$category}', '{$quantityinstock}','{$price}')";
```

Testa se funciona assim, estava faltando aspas simples em alguns campos.. e entre {} fica uma query mais clean!